# A good approach to Temp Records PHP DB per user?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm working on a web application which will take user input, display it and then populate a database only is user clicks a 'Save Button'.

The concept similar to "jsfiddle", where it will allow you to create but not save until user decided, then it will as well create a custom url.

The question is:

What will be a good approach to hold user entries until saved?

- Session Array (which get's pushes to db upon 'save button')
- Temporary Mysql Table Records
- Cookies / Session Combination

Please advice if the question needs more clarification. Question is more towards temporary records. PHP language.

Comment: Your only doubt is what to do with unsaved data? You need exactly the same data structure whether your store into DB or not :-?

Comment: I believe so. I guess a functional scene could be session only data and db insert ad-hoc. Someone suggested the database gets written everything with inactive flags and activate upon user decision. I think both approaches have it's Trade-offs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, you can't store arbitrary amounts of data in a cookie - have a google for the RFCs (IIRC, the limit is set on the size of all cookies for a particular host).

Nor can you use mysql temporary tables - the mysql session session only runs as long as the PHP script - at the end of the **mysql** session (not the PHP session which is a mechanism for making data persist between invocations of the interpreter) , the temporary tables are lost.

The most efficient solution will depend on how often users abandon data entry and the range of sizes in the working set, but the simplest solution would be to store the data in the table where it would eventually be written to - but flag it as a working copy with a link to the user id or session id.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is really dependent on the type of content you are using. For long complicated forms I would use a temporary table entry and copy the content on saving. Just be sure to have system for cleaning out old temp entries.

For less complex issues I would just use a cookies system, either conventionally or use PHP $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

**Are you allowed to use HTML5?**

- *yes*: use [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) which allows you to store a lot of data client-side, needing no further processing on your server. It will survive browser crashes, won't be affected by network of synchronisation issues, and so on.
- *no*: you will need to use cookies for the server to remember what has been chosen by the user. **Is your data going to hold in 4ko?**

  - *yes*: then you can store everything in the cookie, thus not needing to store anything on your server if you want to.
  - *no*: use the PHP session mechanism which stores the session content on your server and only uses the cookie to know where to find the data on the server.

Comment: PHP's session management already implements the structures for managing data on the server referencde by a cookie.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Corrected my answer.